# What makes an argument into an event object?

Tags: javascript

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148728/functionee-something-who-is-e), in a function

```
function(e){
    e.stopPropogation();
}
```

`e` is the event object. But why? Is the first and only argument assumed to be the event? What if there are two arguments? How would I make the second refer to the event instead? Or is it as simple as saying

```
function(something,x){
    x.stopPropogation();
}
```

because I would assume `x` would be undefined, and wouldn't expect it to automatically become an event object by virtue of having event methods called on it.

Comment: This is part of JavaScript "core" - for example it's mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) for Gecko based browsers like Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DOM events, the first argument (*and only one usually*) is the event object.

For frameworks, it depends on the implementation, but to maintain consistency they will usually pass the event in the first parameter as well..

You are right to assume the `x` will be undefined..

have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any DOM events that will pass multiple arguments (without a library)?

Comment: @pimvdb, can't think of any right away. It is very likely that there is none.. but i put the usually to afford corrections :) That is why the event object holds so much information inside it..

Answer (score 1):

That question you reference is specifically about jQuery event handlers.  The event object is the first argument to the handler because that's just how the function is invoked. Nothing forces it to be the event object.

You generally cannot control how event handlers are invoked, though some frameworks will let you pass through additional parameters at the time the handler is bound (which means that the same values would be passed through for each event occurrence) or at the time an event is programatically triggered.