# jquery documentation

Tags: jquery, html, documentation

I want to know what is 'e' (s. following source code) and what member it has. Where do I find a documentation for this kind of stuff? I would like to have "one" documentation for the whole jQuery-API and all parameters. Searching in Google is too time-consuming...

```
$("#idxy").mousedown(function(e) { ... });
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: if you find searching google too time-consuming, you should perhaps practice. It is very easy to find the docs in question.

Comment: "I would like to have "one" documentation for the whole jQuery-API"... Umm, http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: so if it is very easy: Where is the documentation describing mousedown of jQuery and also the member of its parameter 'e'?

Comment: @user1027167 — See all those answers below this question? Most of them link to it.

Comment: @Quentin - see my comment to Matt, jQuery documentation gives not enough information...

Comment: possible duplicate of [function(e){e.something...} who is e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148728/functionee-something-who-is-e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the official [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

In this case, `e` refers to the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), which is passed to all event handlers by jQuery. This differs to a standard Event object in that jQuery normalizes many properties for cross-browser consistency.

One ***extremely*** handy tip is that you can type http://api.jquery.com/methodName and you'll get shown the documentation for that method; try it out;

- http://api.jquery.com/mousedown for the `mousedown()` function
- http://api.jquery.com/attr for the `attr()` function
- http://api.jquery.com/length for the `length` member

... you get the idea ;).

Comment: so in my case i was searching for "e.button = 2", i found out (with the help of google) that this says the right button was clicked. This is not documented in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Yes it is: On http://api.jquery.com/mousedown : The mousedown event is sent when any mouse button is clicked. To act only on specific buttons, we can use the event object's which property. Not all browsers support this property (Internet Explorer uses button instead), but jQuery normalizes the property so that it is safe to use in any browser. The value of which will be 1 for the left button, 2 for the middle button, or 3 for the right button.

Comment: Ohh, i have not seen that, thanks!
So 'which' is defined, but what is the content of 'toElement' in the 'mousedown' event? Seems that the jQuery documentation is not complete.

Comment: @user1027167: You should only use the values which are documented. Many values are internal to jQuery, and there's nothing stopping the values changing/ being removed without warning in a later release. Additionally, some of the values you see are non-standard, and non available/ not normalised by jQuery for x-browser consistency.

Comment: @user1027167: this goes to say (as \@Marijn said), that you should be looking at `event.which` rather than `event.button`, which links to the [MDC charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes) documentation to lookup which each value means.

Comment: Ok, i get it, thanks. So the documentation seems not very intuitively. I had to search and read a lot (in jQuery-Docs and Google again) to find out, that the 'mouseOut' event uses the 'relatedTarget' propertie. A list of all used properties for each event would be a big help...

Comment: @user1027167: I recommend you read [the description given to each event property in the Event object list](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). It should give you an *idea* which property will hold the value you want. The other thing I recommend is to use Developer Tools to inspect the event object received in an event handler, and you'll see exactly what each attribute is assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

e is an event object that gets passed to the function with details of the event that caused it.

The properties will be different depending on what raised the event in the first place, see the JQuery documentation for more details:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: so where is the documentation for the event properties: altKey, attrChange, attrName, bubbles, button, cancelable... and so on

Comment: ABout a quarter of the way down the page:  Event Properties
The following properties are guaranteed to be members of the event object, though some of their values may be undefined, depending on the event:

altKey, attrChange, attrName, bubbles, button, cancelable, charCode, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, currentTarget, data, detail, eventPhase, fromElement, handler, keyCode, layerX, layerY, metaKey, newValue, offsetX, offsetY, originalTarget, pageX, pageY, prevValue, relatedNode, relatedTarget, screenX, screenY, shiftKey, srcElement, target, toElement, view, wheelDelta, which

Comment: I copied my list of event properities from that page. But that is not a documentation, it is a list of properties. What is the content of theses properties for a specific event?

Comment: If you look down the menu bar on the Left, all the various "Event Types" are listed:  Events
Browser Events, Document Loading Event, Form Events, Keyboard Events, Mouse Events.  Each one has separate sub sections describing the different event types and which fields are used, as others have already said.  There is NO one single page that tells you everything you one to know in one go, you'll have to browse around the JQ site.  Everything you want to know is there, you just need to find it.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to have "one" documentation for the whole jQuery-API and all parameters.

[docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

> I want to know what is 'e'

From the [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) page:

> `.mousedown( handler(eventObject) )`

It is an [eventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Answer (score 0):

[jQAPI](http://jqapi.com/) -  Alternative jQuery Documentation has offline `HTML` and `AIR` version.